# Função para formartar horas

Tags: php

Montei a função abaixo que me retorna horas nesse formato `4:5:3` (hora, minuto, segundo).

Gostaria de retornar nesse formato `04:05:03`(hora, minuto, segundo).

```
function converter($time)
{

    if (is_int($time)) {

        $horas    = floor($time / 3600);
        $minutos  = floor(($time - ($horas * 3600)) / 60);
        $segundos = floor($time % 60);

        $newtime = $horas . ":" . $minutos . ":" . $segundos;

    } else {

        echo "o valor deve ser um inteiro";

    }

    return $newtime;

}
```

Comment: Você já tentou usar o date("H:i:s"); ?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode formatar da seguinte forma se `$time` for um timestamp:

```
$horaFormatada = date('H:i:s', $time);
```

Comment: Penso que essa seria a melhor solução.

Answer (score 1):

Tens de apresentar no formato de DateTime, senão ele tira o zero, porque um zero à esquerda não conta.

```
function converter($time)
{

if (is_int($time)) {

    $horas    = floor($time / 3600);
    $minutos  = floor(($time - ($horas * 3600)) / 60);
    $segundos = floor($time % 60);


    $newtime= new DateTime();
    $newtime->setTime($horas, $minutos, $segundos);

} else {

    echo "o valor deve ser um inteiro";

}

return $newtime;

}
```